# jmockit debug binary source mismatch

Tags: java, jmockit

I was debugging an unit test case which used the Jmockit(v1.1), one weird scenario I am encountering is that : one the class was mocked to replace one method implementation. and then when debugging, that class source code become unaligned with its corresponding binary. I confirmed this by debugging   step into a non exist method (looking from source code ).

I tried byte code outline tool on eclipse, but the byte code is basically aligning itself with the source code instead of the real executing byte code.

Tools Used( MVN, eclipse ) and when the error began, there is an error on the debug panel `com.sun.jdi.InternalException: Got error code in reply:35 occurred retrieving this  from stack frame`

how to investigate this kind of source/binary mismatch problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont mention the tools/IDE you are using, but from experience, its possible that the library used by the debbugging IDE mismatchs the runtime one, in my case its was Eclipse+Maven(M2E) using a `provided` scope dependency(ie: you say version 2.1 will be provided but its actually 2.2 at runtime). So the lines from the runtime stack trace would not match the source being displayed by Eclipse.

Comment: I still don't know how to trace the exact reason of this, but we are guessing this is the problem of our IDE (STS, which might be a bit old in terms of eclipse version )